# Download multiple pdf files by using cmd (Windows Command Prompt)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, download, curl

I'm looking for a way to download multiple pdf by using a "single" command in cmd (e.g. from [here](https://www.pi.infn.it/%7Erizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/)). So far I learned how to download a single file by using:

```
curl URL -o name.pdf
```

---

EDIT: I'd like to avoid to use windows subsystem for linux.

---

EDIT 2: it's ok also more than one command.

Comment: Why does it matter that it is in a single command?  Even if it is in a single command.. IT ISN'T.  The single process will STILL need to parse out the work.. no different than if you used multiple processes.

Comment: Hello @SeñorCMasMas it's just a way to be more efficient in terms of time needed to write the command.

Comment: It isn't more efficient by measurable means... or at least not enough to sweat.  That is what I am telling you.  It appears that way but the difference is negligible.  A single process doing the work.. would need to spit into multiple threads.. not a whole lot different than you doing that yourself via multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

These sources URL/page:

[image]

[image]

---

This page has a badly done, unapplied (or badly applied) line break causing a long line on the first occurrence of a .pdf file.

If it weren't for this break (or lack of it), a for loop would do what you need.

Until some editing is done on that page, you can try:

- Command line for the first file (Appunti_campi_scalari_e_vettoriali.pdf)

```
for /f useback^tokens^=18delims^=^" %i in (`curl.exe -H "Accept: text/html" "https://www.pi.infn.it/%7Erizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/" -q ^|findstr \[.*\.pdf`)do @if not exist ".\%~nxi" curl -o "%~i" "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/%~i"
```

- Command line for the remaining files:

```
for /f skip^=1^useback^tokens^=6delims^=^" %i in (`curl.exe -H "Accept: text/html" "https://www.pi.infn.it/%7Erizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/" -q ^|findstr \[.*\.pdf`)do @if not exist ".\%~ni.pdf" curl -o "%~i" "https://www.pi.infn.it/~rizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/%~i"
```

- Some further reading:

  - **[Curl](https://ss64.com/nt/curl.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
  - **[if condition() else condition()](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

Answer (score 0):

With `lftp`:

```
lftp -c 'connect https://www.pi.infn.it/%7Erizzo/ingegneria/appunti_fisII_ing_mecc/; mget *pdf'
```

Comment: Hello @ArkadiuszDrbczyk the cmd says that lftp is not recognized. PS I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I don't use Windows.

Comment: Because OP used `command-line` tag and lftp works in the command line.

Comment: Sorry @ArkadiuszDrbczyk, maybe should I remote the tag command-line?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: well I don't know, these days you can easily run Linux apps on Windows using WSL but you said you'd prefer to avoid it. Notice that Linux has been historically more command-line oriented than Windows world and that some things are hard to do on Windows.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrbczyk thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Oh... and I like your answer.  That is how >I< would do it too. :)  .. he was specific about using cmd.exe and that means windows.  I too thank you for your contribution.